# a single, fairly sophisticated word that describes one's desire to be unique

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Or honestly, desire to be any particular trait, specifically one trait (ex. Wanderlust: the desire to travel and experience the world.) I'm not looking for any sort of contextual consistency here. Just wondering! Reverse look ups are hard.

Comment: I had a look at "English words with philia suffix" but there was no _unusphilia_ - hereby coined

Comment: How about "Hipster"? ;P

Comment: *Idiosyncratic* comes to mind, as it pertains to something unique to someone.  Not sure if it widely carries a positive connotation.  *Sui generis* is another word that means *one of a kind*.  Unfortunately, neither seems to convey the desire to be unique :-(

Comment: Why not try [philosophy.se] ?

Comment: To be honest I really don't think it's that clear what you're asking.  Maybe give some example sentences with the "word missing".  Do you mean someone who is "striving" or "driven" .. as that can be used with "any particular" direction.  For example, I am driven to the scientific worldview; my sister is driven to kindness; my brother strives for greater world experiences .. etc ?

Answer (score 1):

a **non-conformist** is someone who doesn't conform to typical social norms. This is often reflected in dress style. It can be reflected in other behaviours as well.

The term can be used as a literal descriptor ('That person is a bit of a non-conformist'), or a description reflecting one's desires ('I got all these piercings to show society what a non-conformist I am').

Answer (score 0):

You could use the term **special/unique/precious snowflake** sarcastically to describe someone who acts like there is something unique and special to them.

The phrase comes from the trope that no two snowflakes are alike.

> Well aren't you a precious snowflake! We'd better cherish you.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The expression *[one and only](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/one+and+only)*  may convey the idea of uniqueness:

> - eminent beyond or above comparison;

Also the expression [an absolute gem](http://www.wordsense.eu/gem/)  is  used to refer to someone who is rare and valued.

> - figuratively - any precious or highly valued thing or person
> - She's an absolute gem.

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/one+and+only

Answer (score 0):

***Individualism***, in general, has the sense of desire to be unique and is the sentiment of uniqueness but it goes deeper in political philosophy.

> Individualism is the moral stance, political philosophy, ideology, or social outlook that emphasizes the moral worth of the individual.  Individualists promote the exercise of one's goals and desires and so value independence and self-reliance...
>
> It has also been used as a term denoting "The quality of being an individual; individuality" related to possessing "An individual characteristic; a quirk."
>
> <sub>Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individualism</sub>

An example from *Peer Gynt* (a five-act play in verse by the Norwegian dramatist Henrik Ibsen):

> As personal will to life **individualism is a desire to “be oneself**,” according to the wish of a character from Ibsen (Peer Gynt), a desire for independence and originality. The individualist wants to be his own maker, his own furnisher of truth and illusion; his own builder of truth and illusion; his own builder of dreams; his own builder and demolisher of ideals.
>
> <sub>Source: https://www.marxists.org/archive/palante/1914/pessimism.htm</sub>

Comment: Seems to work, though the term is understood variously in various contexts and is rather vaguely defined. *Under the shiny surface there's homelessness, ignorance, insane people on the streets, hypocrisy, a certain coldness and strong **individualism** in people in general.*

Comment: @Kris: Yes, it depends on the context. I mentioned the broader usage of the word as well. But this might be the closest fit that includes not just being unique but the "desire" also.